# Visual Studio Code auto compiling every EXACT minute in React project

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, web-compiler

For some reason, my VScode keeps auto-compiling every 60 seconds on my React project (generated by create-react-app). I tried disabling all extensions but even then the issue persists. I have validated that files are not saved when this compiling occurs.

I would really appreciate any tips on what could be causing this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that it's related to vscode? How do you run your project?

Comment: I'm not sure it's related to vscode, I can't quite track what's the source behind it. I run my project with the npm start command

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue, in tailwind.config.js I had set the value of content to [../*]. I changed it to ['./public/index.html'] and the issue has stopped (: